# How can I start resque workers on my staging and production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, resque

I have a rails4 app, built with angular.js on frontend. I am using Resque for the cron tasks but on my staging and production servers, there are 0 workers. How can I start the resque workers manually? Is there a way to start workers automatically after the code is deployed. I am using capistrano for deployment. I have not yet tried any other gem for eg: God, capistrano-resque. Do you recommend using a gem for just this?

[image: workers:0]

Answer (score 0):

Just write a capistrano task for starting the redis-server and your resque workers.

You can then hook it up in your deploy.rb on the after "deploy:restart" event or something.

Also refer to
http://railscasts.com/episodes/133-capistrano-tasks

That should get you up to speed.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

We are using [capistrano-resque](https://github.com/sshingler/capistrano-resque) for the exact same thing. It does exactly that: start your workers in production. We decided against god or foreman+upstart for just starting workers as we needed them up quickly and considered them too heavy for just doing that.